# What causes blotchy printing on a dye-sub (ribbon) printer

Tags: printer

I just bought a DNP DS40 dye-sub (dye sublimation) printer on eBay for a little side project.  I mainly was testing to see if my corners would fit on the print and noticed the left side printed very blotchy.  About 2/3rds of the left side doesn't print solid. I've cleaned the print head with alcohol and the results didn't change.

Next I jiggled the print thinking it's not making full contact and my results did greatly improve.  Now only the left 1/3rd is slightly blotchy.  I attached a photo of the first version.
[image: blotchy dyesub prints]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the printer may have been dropped and the head isn't aligned proper now.

Answer (score 1):

Most common causes:

1. Dirty printhead
2. Wrinkles or creases in media that cause media to lift away from printhead